# Visual Workflow Launches Blank - Cannot See Existing Flows

Tags: visual-workflow

**The problem**: When I attempt to open an existing flow, Visual Workflow takes a significant amount of time to load. When it does load, the flow appears as a blank, unsaved flow. This issue seems to be linked to a specific computer, I'm able to access flows normally on other machines.

**Attempted fixes**: This is the troubleshooting I've done so far:

- Tried different browsers (Chrome, Firefox, IE)
- Uninstalled and re-installed flash
- Disabled the pepper flash in Chrome
- Used a different computer (this works)

Has anyone else encountered this issue? Any ideas where else to look?

Answer (score 1):

I have had the exact same problem and nothing seems to work. I've done the exact steps but the results were exactly the same.

I am using a Mac if that makes a difference. I have never used a different computer though as this Mac is the only one I have.